# ServiceStack.net - Routes for searching?

Tags: servicestack

Take the simple example of searching for a `Customer` entity based on different criteria:

```
public class Customer : IReturn<CustomerDTO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

I then have the following routes setup:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    Routes
       .Add<Customer>("/customers", "GET")
       .Add<Customer>("/customers/{Id}", "GET")
       .Add<Customer>("/customers/{LastName}", "GET");
}
```

This does not seem to work. How do I define separate routes to enable search criteria on different fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2 rules are clashing, i.e. they both match the route `/customers/x`:

```
.Add<Customer>("/customers/{Id}", "GET")
.Add<Customer>("/customers/{LastName}", "GET");
```

By default this rule:

```
.Add<Customer>("/customers", "GET")
```

Also lets you populate the Request DTO using the QueryString, e.g:

```
/customers?Id=1
/customers?LastName=foo
```

So with just these 2 rules:

```
.Add<Customer>("/customers", "GET")
.Add<Customer>("/customers/{Id}", "GET")
```

Lets you query with:

```
/customers
/customers/1
/customers?LastName=foo
```

If you want LastName accessible with the /pathinfo you need to use a non-clashing route, e.g:

```
.Add<Customer>("/customers/by-name/{LastName}", "GET")
```

For more info, see the [Routing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing).

Comment: So are the query parameters case sensitive? They have to match the case of the properties on the request object?

Comment: @Sam the properties are case-insensitive.